# Android Expandable List groups textView random replace

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

Friends,

I am having a problem with Expandable List - for the first time the list groups are drawn correctly, (respective textViews texts get replaced, e.g. *3 of 9*) but when any of groups are clicked the textViews of another group (random) are replaced instead of beeing untouched *mm*.

[image: correct]

[image: faulty]

What should be done to prevent this?

Here is the adapter class:

```
public class InterestListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
...
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(_context).inflate(R.layout.activity_interest_list_group, parent, false);
    }

    try
    {
        HashMap<String, String> interest = this._listDataHeader.get(String.valueOf(groupPosition));

        String interestId = interest.get("interest_id");
        String interestName = interest.get("interest_name");

        JSONObject interestsTree = new JSONObject(library.loadString(_context, "userInterestsTree"));

        TextView listGroupName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.interest_list_group_name);
        listGroupName.setText(interestName);

        if (this._listDataChild.containsKey(String.valueOf(interestId)))
        {
            String subinterestAll = String.valueOf(this._listDataChild.get(String.valueOf(interestId)).size());

            if (interestsTree.has(interestId))
            {
                String subinterestChecked = interestsTree.getString(interestId);
                TextView subinterestText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.interest_list_group_selected);
                subinterestText.setText(subinterestChecked + " of " + subinterestAll);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("error", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm rather sure, that you have problems with memory management. When you expand your list some cells become hidden from the screen. After then, when you scroll it, they have to be regenerated. Android OS, to save memory, doesn't generate them from scratch, but instead of that uses the same memory regions, that were used for hidden cells.

It looks like subinterestText is the problematic field. It's being set only if both these ifs are true:

```
if (this._listDataChild.containsKey(String.valueOf(interestId)))
```

and

```
if (interestsTree.has(interestId))
```

If one of them is false, subinterestText variable won't be set. So, as result, value will be usedfrom previously hidden field - in your case - 2 of 2.

To fix it - always setup all values of your cell in getGroupView method.